# How to draw a single colorbar between the two figures?

Tags: python, colorbar

I drew figures using `Basemap` and `scatter`. And I wanted to draw a colorbar.
I did the following to draw a figure that wasn't strange, but it wasn't the result I wanted.

```
def def_basemap(ax):
    m = Basemap(projection="merc", resolution="l", ax=ax,
                lat_0=37.35, lon_0=126.58,
                urcrnrlat=44, llcrnrlat=32, llcrnrlon=121.5, urcrnrlon=132.5)
    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.drawcountries()
    m.drawmapboundary()
    return m


fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,10))
axes_ = ax.ravel().tolist()
base_ = [def_basemap(axes_[i]) for i in range(4)] # create basemap

# lon & lat, values
lon  = np.linspace(121.5, 132.5, 10)
lat  = np.linspace(32, 44, 10)
val1 = np.random.random((10,10))

lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
X, Y = zip(*[base_[i](lons, lats) for i in range(3)])

#-----------------Contourf-----------------#
for i in range(3):
  cbar = axes_[i].contourf(X[i], Y[i], val1)
  cb   = fig.colorbar(cbar, ax=axes_[i])

#-----------------Scatter------------------#
X2, Y2 = base_[-1](lon, lat)
val2 = np.random.random(10)
val2_sorted = sorted(val2)

cols = val2_sorted
size = np.linspace(100, 500, 10) * 2
sbar = axes_[-1].scatter(X2, Y2, s=size, c=cols)
cb2  = fig.colorbar(sbar, ax=axes_[-1])

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Figure01]

I revised it as follows...

```
#-----------------Contourf-----------------#
...
cbar_ = []
for i in range(3):
  cbar = axes_[i].contourf(X[i], Y[i], val1)
  cbar_.append(cbar)

cb = fig.colorbar(cbar_[0], ax=axes_[0:2], orientation="horizontal")
...
```

[image: Figure02]

As a result, I got a very weird figure.
I want to draw one colorbar in the middle of the four figures, and one colorbar in the scatter figure at the same time.

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.